# Clean flush data from a loop in Comet?

Tags: php, html

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
ob_implicit_flush(1);
for ($i = 0, $level = ob_get_level(); $i < $level; $i++) { ob_end_flush(); } //Flush all levels of the buffer to start
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$x = 0;
while(true){
    echo $x++;
    sleep(2);
}
?>
```

And here is my HTML code

```
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log( xmlhttp.response );
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

When I run this program output is

```
0 , 01 , 012 , 0123 ......
```

How I get the output just like that without using JavaScript replace function

```
0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ....
```

Comment: maybe you need to do flush in the while loop. Or you can issue ajax requests every 1 seconds from the script. Maintain the counter in session